# MVC IAuthenticationFilter Windows Authentication Overwriting principal and caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, caching, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

Sorry in advance for the essay.

I have an MVC application which uses windows authentication.
A number of roles and 'system actions' have been stored in a database.
I've created a custom principal which has a base of ClaimsPrincipal.
I've also created an AuthenticationFilter which implements IAuthenticationFilter.
In the filter, i create a new instance of my custom principal, add the roles and 'system actions' as claims, and then assign it to the filter.Principal.

From there i have a custom AuthorizationAttribute which will make use of these roles and system actions. (i.e. each controller/action will have a [CustomAuthorizationAttribute(Roles = "blah", SystemActions = "blah")])

Additionally - i have a disclaimer page - which when the user agrees, needs to store a claim in my CustomPrincipal. my custom authorization attribute then checks to see if that claim exists.

Now that the background is out of the way;
The issue is that i need to cache this principal somehow - so that i don't have to hit the database on every request.
Am i best to store it in session? Or a cookie? Or is there some other way to do it?
What are the pros and cons of each?
I was leaning towards using a cookie - although this decision is not made with much knowledge of the pros/cons of each (hence the above question).
How would i go about implementing the cookie?

From the disclaimer page, i would then need to add my 'DisclaimerAccepted' claim, and update the cache.

AuthFilter code for reference:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        var principal = new CustomPrincipal(filterContext.Principal);

        var roles = GetRolesForUser(principal.Identity.Name);
        var systemActions = new List<SystemAction>();

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            principal.AddRole(role.Name);
            systemActions.AddRange(GetSystemActionsForRole(role.Id));
        }

        principal.AddSystemActions(systemActions.Select(a => a.Name));

        filterContext.Principal = principal;
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that i need to cache this principal somehow - so that i
>   don't have to hit the database on every request. Am i best to store it
>   in session?

You can use OWIN Cookie middleware in which we store claims inside cookie so that we only query database once.

On subsequent request, OWIN Cookie Middleware retrieves the claims from the cookie, and add those to Principle object.

> Additionally - i have a disclaimer page - which when the user agrees,
>   needs to store a claim in my CustomPrincipal.

If you want to add new claims, you will need to call `authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);` again.

### [Startup.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Startup.cs)

Configure OWIN Cookie Middleware at startup.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourApplication.Startup))]
namespace YourApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### [OwinAuthenticationService](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security/OwinAuthenticationService.cs#L10)

```
public class OwinAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _context;
    private const string AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie";

    public OwinAuthenticationService(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SignIn(User user)
    {
        IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
        };

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationType);

        IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

        authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

        authenticationManager.SignOut(AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

*You can look at my working sample project at [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin).*

Comment: I dont want to use a login page - the app is using Windows authentication.
Is it possible to get the owin context from within my authentication filter?